# Import data from MySql to Stata

Tags: mysql, stata

I have a MySql table with more than 100,000 records and would like to analyse the data in Stata. Is there any way to import the MySql table in Stata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use ODBC](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dodbc.pdf) or [a plugin](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/using-plugin-to-connect-to-database/) to directly connect Stata to MySQL; or you can export the data from MySQL (e.g. to a CSV file, via [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html)) and then [import](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dimportdelimited.pdf) into Stata.